# why does it show "unable to find listener" error on executing "DriverManager.getConnection("credentials")" when running the servlet continuously?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, servlets, jdbc

When I run the following servlet for multiple times continuously it gets stuck at the "drivermanager.getconnection" part after inserting few rows of datas and i can't continue the process. I have to restart the whole web app to continue the process from where it stuck. Can anybody please help me know what is the problem here ? What additional things need to be done here to avoid the problem? I am using properties file, callable statement, prepared statement, but none is solving the issue.

```
/*all the imports*/

public class PtRegSer extends HttpServlet {



protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)     throws ServletException, IOException {

    /*values to put in the table*/
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    Connection conn=null;
    Statement stmn=null;
    try
    {
        System.out.println("1");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:xyz","system","123456");
        System.out.println("2");
        stmn=conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("3");            
        stmn.execute("insert into ptregt values('"+pregno+"','"+pname+"','"+pgender+"','"+page+"','"+paddr+"','"+ptrtmnt+"','"+pdoc+"','"+prfee+"','"+preguser+"',to_date('"+pdate+"','yyyy-MM-dd'))");     
        b=true;
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried closing the statement and the connection?

Comment: 1) Use a connection pool, 2) you are never closing the connection which might lead to connection errors.

Comment: Thank you LukeWoodward and MarkRotteveel....I hadn't closed the statement and connections. Still a learner even while working on a real time project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@chao dee
This is a snippet of code of a project I have done earlier, hope this can help you
**Web.xml for passing init parameters**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>db-URL</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.88.128:1521:orcl</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>db-Username</param-name>
    <param-value>hr</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>db-Password</param-name>
    <param-value>hr</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**Listener Class:**

```
public class AppServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{
      public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
      {
            ServletContext context=event.getServletContext();
            String url=context.getInitParameter("db-URL");
            String username=context.getInitParameter("db-Username");
            String password=context.getInitParameter("db-Password");
            DbManager mydb=new DbManager(url,username,password);
            context.setAttribute("Database", mydb);

      }
      public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)
      {
           ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
           context.removeAttribute("Database");
      }
}
```

**Using it in a servlet**

```
DbManager db = (DbManager) getServletContext().getAttribute("Database");
    Connection con = db.getConnection();
    try {
        String query = "INSERT into ADD_CUSTOMER values ('" + customer.getFirstName() + "','" + customer.getLastName() + "','" + customer.getAddress() + "','" + customer.getCity() + "','" + customer.getPostalCode() + "','" + customer.getEmail() + "'," + customer.getPhoneNumber() + ",'" + customer.getUserEmail() + "'," + customer.getCustomerType() + ")";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(query); //Error Handling to be done
        st.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

**My DbManager Class (its not necessary, but a good practice)**

public class DbManager {

```
private Connection conDb;

public Connection getConnection() {
    return conDb;
}

public DbManager(String url, String username, String password) {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        this.conDb = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is that you didn't closed connection and statement. 
Moreover, I would like to add that your servlet is not programmed according to good practice, database connections should be initialized and destroyed in context listeners which creates a connection when web is first started and close it when context is destroyed and should be saved to servlet context and in all servlets, connection should be retrieved from the servlet context.
Statements ONLY should be made and destroyed in the servlets, however i would prefer preparedStatements if query is to be executed repeatedly.

Comment: could you please show me how to initialize and destroy database connections in context listener and to save in servlet context.